# Text Classification Problem : Name and approach of this type of classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I have a labelled data-set comprising of text segments and corresponding labels. Each label consists of three parts, and there can be multiple or zero labels assigned to a given text segment.

```
Sample Data is given below:

text segment                              action        performed       person  
 ---                                       ---           ---             ---
"I went outside to play and not drink."   {play,drink}  {yes,no}        {1st,1st}
"He is not playing."                       play          no              3rd
"The weather is cold today."               N/A           N/A             N/A
```

The task is to predict the label for any given text segment, where each label consists of three parts (action, performed, person), and there may be zero or more labels for a text segment.

There are fifteen classifiers for action, two for performed, and two for person. Annotated data size is 6000 text segments, in which 4000 text segments are assigned at least one label.

What is this type of text classification called (other than multi-class labelling)?

Also, which classification approach is recommended for this type of classification problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a classification problem. Although you could perhaps torture a classification model for this purpose, the NLP technique you need is "dependency parsing" and "semantic role labeling". Spacy is a good python library for doing dependency parsing.

Comment: In case this problem needs to be solved through a classification model, would it be requiring three separate models to be trained (one for each component of the label) ?